# android layout with buttons overlapped with each other

Tags: android, android-layout, breadcrumbs

[image: How breadcrumb should look like]

how to set the buttons as in the above figure. In ios its been called as breadcrumb style.

I tried placing the buttons in relative layout with one button in middle and other two at both sides but still there is a gap between all buttons and in different devices it looks very horrible.

Following is my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/TBtnLayout"      
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
            android:background="@drawable/title_bar">
                <ImageButton
                    android:contentDescription="@string/btn_desc"
                    android:id="@+id/left_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center_btn"
                    android:background="@drawable/s_unsel_btn">
                </ImageButton>

                <ImageButton 
                    android:contentDescription="@string/btn_desc"
                    android:id="@+id/center_btn"   
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"              
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/c_unsel_btn">
                </ImageButton>

                <ImageButton
                    android:contentDescription="@string/btn_desc"
                    android:id="@+id/right_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center_btn"
                    android:background="@drawable/t_sel_btn">
                </ImageButton>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using a negative margin? something like:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/TBtnLayout"      
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
    android:background="@drawable/title_bar">
        <ImageButton
            android:contentDescription="@string/btn_desc"
            android:id="@+id/left_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="-10dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center_btn"
            android:background="@drawable/s_unsel_btn">
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton 
            android:contentDescription="@string/btn_desc"
            android:id="@+id/center_btn"   
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"              
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/c_unsel_btn">
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:contentDescription="@string/btn_desc"
            android:id="@+id/right_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center_btn"
            android:background="@drawable/t_sel_btn">
        </ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can play with the values till it suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Which is the API level you are using?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentBreadCrumbs.html

if your buttons still have a gap try using android:paddingLeft="0dp" or android:paddingRight="0dp" in xml

Comment: My API level is 14, is there any sample code or tutorial for this. the android padding is not working....any how thanx